# Delete consecutives values in ArrayList of Int

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an `ArrayList` with about 30 000 values, after been sorted, I have lot of consecutive values, for example:

22001 22002 22003 22004 22010 22011 22020

And I want to have : 22001 22004 22010 22011 22020

```
ArrayList<Long> l = new ArrayList<Long>(); // with my values
Collections.sort(l);
ArrayList<Long> liste = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

Comment: You want to save ranges in your ArrayList, but how do you know the range is from 22001-22004 instead of 22004-22010? You may want to consider another `Object` for saving these values that is better suited. Also, please retag the language you're using (I assume Java).

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem, since 22010 and 22011 are consecutive.. If you explain it better, I'll be able to post an answer!

Comment: He is trying to store the start and ending of each range. If not part of a range store the single value. A range of two would thus result in two consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't test it, but it should work (for lists containing 3 or more elements). It's unoptimized regarding memory usage.

```
ArrayList<Long> resultList= new ArrayList<Long>();
Long prevNumber= l.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < l.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (prevNumber.equals(l.get(i) - 1) && l.get(i + 1).equals(l.get(i) + 1)) {
        //print 'inbetween' consecutive number
    } else {
        //not a consecutive, copy it to result list
        resultList.add(l.get(i));
    }
    prevNumber= l.get(i);
}
```

Comment: I love you. Really.
I just added the last value, and it's perfect, thank you very much dude.

Comment: well, a brief look into the code, it seems to me that this logic only works with a list with 3 or more elements.

Answer (score 0):

The simple example of code to solve the issue:

```
    int[] data =new int[] {22001, 22002, 22003, 22004,22005, 22010, 22011, 22020};

    System.out.println(data[0]); //The first element

    for(int current = 1; current < data.length-1; current++) {
        if(data[current+1] - data[current-1] != 2) {
            System.out.println(data[current]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(data[data.length-1]);//The last element
```

Comment

How this work ?

We do not have to check that next item is greater then one. What we are more interested is that do the item after next is distanced by two from the current.

In other words, if left neighbor is smaller by one and right neighbor is greater by one then exclude this element.

Comment: read the question carefully. he wants the sub list, does not want to just print the sub list on console

Comment: @tgkprog, Yep. How do i represent the result is second topic the key is the condition. I assume that future developers are keen enough to write their own solution.

Comment: same to another answer, this will only work if the list contains 3 or more elements.

Comment: @AdrianShum, Beside this is simplified code you are wrong. I will work properly for array with at least two items. But the input validation is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem can be greatly simplified to:

loop thru the list, and when current number is not previous number + 1, then add current and prev value to a result Set.

Which means, instead of thinking of "adding start and end for consecutive range", think of "adding the two sides when you encountered a gap".

psuedo code:

```
Set<Integer> resultSet = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();

Integer prev = null;

for (Integer d : data) {
  if (prev == null) {  // first number
    resultSet.add(d);
  } else if (d != prev + 1) {  // a gap encountered
    resultSet.add(prev);
    resultSet.add(d);
  }
  prev = d;
}

if (prev != null) {  // last number
  resultSet.add(prev);
}

// resultSet will contain what you want.
```